# PHP row background color even/odd

Tags: php

i have a static table(the ID is incremented through a loop and the rest are just repeated),
I want to change the background of the even rows to red and odd rows to blue. i want to to do it with for and if.
MY CODE:

````php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>serial</th>
        <th>pds_number</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>familySize</th>
        <th>voucher_Value</th>
        <th>phone</th>
    </tr>
    
    <?php
     for ( $i = 1; $i < 12 ; $i++ ) { 
      if( $i % 2 == 0 ) {
        echo '<tr bgcolor="red"><td></td></tr>';
      }
      else {
        echo '<tr bgcolor="blue"><td></td></tr>';
      }  
    ?>
  
   <tr>
    <td> <?php echo "$i"; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo "a001" ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo "1234"; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo "nn"; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo "1"; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo "100"; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo "077011111"; ?></td>
   </tr>

<?php  } ?>

</table>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Odd and Even Rows for a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851816/odd-and-even-rows-for-a-table)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please try searching before posting a new question - there are so many examples of this here already, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/easiest-way-to-alternate-row-colors-in-php-html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410534/zebra-stripe-php-mysql-table, https://stackoverflow.com/q/14650954/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3034511/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37399414/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/29096880/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4875456/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12318004/6089612 ... (there are many more).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to alternate row colors in PHP/HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/easiest-way-to-alternate-row-colors-in-php-html)

Answer (score 4):

This is better solved in CSS, like this:

```html
<style>
  table tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: red;
  }
  table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: thank you for answering but i want to do with for loops and if conditions

Comment: @sarah why? This technique is much more efficient

Comment: @sarah If you really want to do it in Html, then you need to color each <td> of a row as you can not color the <tr>. Secondly do not use Html attributes like bgcolor="red" as they have been deprecated some years ago. Use the style attribute like this: <td style="background-color: red;">...</td>

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

````
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>serial</th>
        <th>pds_number</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>familySize</th>
        <th>voucher_Value</th>
        <th>phone</th>
    </tr>
    
    <?php 
for ($i=1; $i <12 ; $i++) { 
  if($i%2==0) {
     echo '<tr style="background-color:red;"><td></td></tr>';
    }
    else {
echo '<tr style="background-color:blue;"><td></td></tr>';

    }  
     
    ?>
  
   <tr>
    <td> <?php echo "$i"; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo "a001" ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo "1234"; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo "nn"; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo "1"; ?></td>
                        <td> <?php echo "100"; ?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo "077011111"; ?></td>
   </tr>

<?php  } ?>

</table>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: didnt make  any difference, only a small line under the rows changes color not the whole row

Comment: if you would like to change color, I prefer css. What is your issue? The color hasn't changed?

Comment: true, but i want to do with if conditions as iam not so good at it and to learn more, a small blue/red line appears under the rows. instead of the color of the whole rows changing